# Download multiple images from URL and upload to aws s3 from aws lambda (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, async-await

I can use this code to upload a **single** image to s3. When I try multiple, only the first item is uploaded and lambda stops executing. I'm new to javascript so I don't understand the problem here.

```
async function downloadImage(url) {
  var options = {
        uri: url,
        encoding: null
    };
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) { 
            console.log("failed to get image");
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            s3.putObject({
                Body: body,
                Key: 'template/'+url.split('/').pop(),
                Bucket: bucketName
            }, function(error, data) { 
                if (error) {
                    console.log("error downloading image to s3");
                } else {
                    console.log("success uploading to s3");
                }
            }); 
        }   
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("error");
  });
}

exports.handler = async (event, _ctx, _cb) => {
  var images = {
    banner: "http://media.com/strip.png",
    icon: "http://media.com/icon.png",
    logo: "http://media.com/logo.png"
  }
  
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(images)) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    await downloadImage(value);
  }
}
```

The output I get from lambda for this:

```
2020-10-03T19:11:32.293Z    3cd401a6-08c6-49a2-b01c-99d6430ffc1a    INFO    banner: http://media.com/circle/strip.png
2020-10-03T19:11:33.201Z    3cd401a6-08c6-49a2-b01c-99d6430ffc1a    INFO    success uploading to s3
```

Comment: do not use async and await inside the downloadImage function as you have already used it in the handler, and after console.log("success uploading to s3"); write a return;

Comment: maybe the timeout of the lambda...

Comment: @Rolstan D'souza When I remove the async and await in the download function, the lambda outputs all three image keys and objects, but doesn't upload any image to s3 or show a success message

Comment: @Derek Menénedez The lambda stops execution after 900ms but the timeout is set to 3 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const downloadImage = async url => {
  const options = {
    uri: url,
    encoding: null
  };
  const image = await requestPromise(options);
  await uploadToS3(image, url);
  return 'Uploaded'
}

const requestPromise = options => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
        console.log("failed to get image: ", error);
        return reject(error);
      }
      resolve(body);
    })
  })
}

const uploadToS3 = (body, url) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.putObject({
      Body: body,
      Key: 'template/' + url.split('/').pop(),
      Bucket: bucketName
    }, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("error downloading image to s3", err);
        return reject(err)
      };
      resolve(data);
    });
  })
}

exports.handler = async (event, _ctx, _cb) => {
  try {
    const images = {
      banner: "http://media.com/strip.png",
      icon: "http://media.com/icon.png",
      logo: "http://media.com/logo.png"
    }
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(images)) {
      console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
      await downloadImage(value);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error in handler: ', error);
    return error
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It works! Could you please kindly explain how this works or what I was doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: You are welcome! Your `downloadImage` is a very bad solution. Also, You don't have resolve/reject/return in there. So it won't work correctly. Your loop cant goes to the next iteration. Please mark the answer as useful if it is.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to mark the answer as useful.

Comment: No problem! Don't worry!

Comment: A more typical approach would be to map over the images array and await Promise.all() on the resulting array of promises.

Comment: I agree @jarmod!